# phpmailer send file from radio button

Tags: php, phpmailer

[view & select files in a directory](http://i115.photobucket.com/albums/n282/CApO_MAfiOsO/a-1.png)

The image above shows a list of uploaded files in a directory. I'm able to view & select a file in the directory (using php), but I don't know how to send/email it as attachment (via phpmailer).

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to use google.com? There are billions of the articles about how to send emails in php

Comment: Yes I already know how to make a working upload form with email function in php. The thing is I can only choose files from local PC. What I wanna try right now is to choose files from a directory/server :)

Comment: there is no difference between server and "local PC". They are both computers

Comment: Have u seen the linked image? The situation is I have a predefined list of files (already uploaded) on my web server. I'm able to choose a file using radio button (eg: test.txt) but I'm not able to submit it as attachment. Thx btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you list the files and select one of them, you'll get the path for that file. After you have the path, you can follow the instructions [here](http://zainal.wordpress.com/2007/01/10/sending-email-attachments-in-php-using-phpmailer-class/) to send it as an attachment.

**Edit after reading comments to original question:** You have the selected filename "text.txt" and you know where in the server those files live. Do something like:

```
$filename = "text.txt";
$path = "/foo/bar/baz" . $filename;
send_email_with_attachment($path);
```

The send_email_with_attachment is a function you need to create yourself, using the info on the link I provided.